# Extract administrative boundaries

Tags: openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries, overpass-api

I'm looking to create maps of administrative boundaries. Sometimes nested. For example I want to create shapefiles or geojson-files for all the countries in the world, including states in the US and counties in Texas. Searching on gis.stackexchange mostly pointed to http://overpass-turbo.eu. But overpass looks like it's geared to interactive usage. Furthermore the software has to run on my own server.

Being a newbie to gis and mapping software, any pointers to books or blogs or whatever that could help me would be welcome too.

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overpass can also be used in "script"-mode. All queries can be formulated as http-requests to the Overpass server. Overpass Turbo is only for interactive queries

There is already a service providing the information that you need, unfortunately the server seems to be down for maintenance at the moment. However, you can find some information about it on http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Wambacher#Boundaries_Map